# Call to undefined relationship - Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using latest `Laravel`.
I have method in the controller which selects from table and data from relational table, too:

```
$cars= Car::with(array('car_photos'=>function($query){
    $query->select('id');
}))->get();
```

`Cars` has many photos. Car model:

```
public function photos(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\CarPhoto');
}
```

`CarPhoto` model:

```
public function car(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Car');
}
```

I can select all photos for a car with:

```
$car= Car::where('id', $id)->first();
$photos = $car->photos;
```

but with `$cars= Car::with....`, I am getting:

> Call to undefined relationship [car_photos] on model [App\Models\Car].

Comment: Is this supposed to be a many-to-many relationship? If so, you need to use a `belongsToMany` with the `Car` and `Photo` models. Generally, you don't have a model for the `pivot` table, in this case `CarPhoto`. See https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many for full details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relation name not class name:

```
  $cars= Car::with(array('photos'=>function($query){
        $query->select('id');
    }))->get();
```

Comment: This returns me `object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)#1785 (1) {
  ["items":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}`

Comment: But I am sure there are photos, because I can query with the same `car_id` and check for images for this specific car row.

Comment: In the foreach '$car->photos' or `$car['photos']`, both are empty.

Comment: This is because I am selecting and specific columns `->get('column', ..)`, and `get` inside relation, give me same empty array.